# preg_replace_callback, callback's return value don't replace the matched string

Tags: php, pcre, preg-replace-callback

In the following snippet

Why doesn't **bar** replace **foo**?

```
$subject = "Hello foo";

preg_replace_callback(
    '/\bfoo\b/i',

    function ($match)
    {
        return 'bar';
    },

    $subject
 );

 echo $subject;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`preg_replace_callback`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php#refsect1-function.preg-replace-callback-returnvalues) does not modify `$subject` but returns the new string:

The following code should work:

```
$subject = "Hello foo";

echo preg_replace_callback(
    '/\bfoo\b/i',

    function ($match)
    {
        return 'bar';
    },

    $subject
 );
```